# How to blur or hide runner thumbnails?

Tags: html, css

I trying to blur or hide  runner thumbnails on various streaming sites (PrimeVideo for example)  I use Amino: Live CSS Editor chrome extension in most cases or uBlock Origin when I hide or blur certain elements from websites. But I can't understand how to blur that element. I mean these runner thumbnails don't even have `divs`, they just appear when you hover your mouse over progress bar and then disappear. With this css:

```
div.fmugii2.atvwebplayersdk-seekbar-container {
      display: none;
}
```

entire progress bar became hidden, but I want only to hide thumbnails which appear over seekbar when you hover mouse over it.

Can someone give me a hint how to blur that element or hide completely from pop up, maybe need to use other tool for that? As in picture below is exactly what I want to hide or blur.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to the img you want to blur, find a way to select it, and add to it:

```
.[selectorToImg]{
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

Comment: Problem is to select this element since its only pop up after hover to another element (seekbar which is on primevideo have this div: div.fmugii2.atvwebplayersdk-seekbar-container ) And it disappear when i want to click on it to select.   So when i add to it     {
  filter: blur(5px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}            i get blurred seekbar but thumbnail is still the same.  Actually youtube have the same  runner thumbnails i talking about,  so you can try yourself to understand what i mean.

Comment: try `div.fmugii2.atvwebplayersdk-seekbar-container img`

Comment: It worked.  Thank you very much !!!

Comment: glad to hear this, you're welcome :)

Comment: if it solved your issue, mark it as `accepted` so other users know that this is the solution